# Where to put the CSS in the reason react template?

Tags: reason-react

I've created a project using `bsb -init my-react-app -theme react` and I build it with `npm start` and `npm run webpack`. Where can I put my CSS files so that they are included in the build?

I've tried `src/` but unlike `index.html` it is not copied to `build/`.

Answer (score 0):

you can import css like how you usually do in React, just make sure that you have css loader in your WebPack.

```
[%bs.raw {|require('./myCss.css')|}];
```

or you use some plugins like [bs-emotion](https://github.com/parkerziegler/bs-emotion) is one my favourite.

```
open Emotion

let button = [%css [ ... ]]

<div className=button>...
```